# Running Laravel and AngularJS on NGINX

Tags: angularjs, laravel, nginx, laravel-4

I run Laravel for the back-end and the AngularJS for the front-end. My application hierarchy is

```
/application
    /app
    /bootstrap
    /vendor   
    /public
        /api 
            index.php <-- This is the Laravel "public" index
        index.html
        bootstrap.js
```

So basically, the default `public` folder is used for AngularJS front end, and the `/public/api` is used for the Laravel.

I cannot figure out how to write the NGINX config! This is what I have so far

```
server {
        listen   80;

        root PATH_TO_PUBLIC;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name mysite.com;

        # AnuglarJS UI Front /index.html
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/
        }

        # Laravel Back-end /api/index.php
        location /api/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri / =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

The only page from Laravel that works is `/api/index.php`. Even something like `/api/index.php/my-resource` does not work either.

**Edit**

When I visit `/api/index.php`, Laravel kicks in and works. When I visit any other page (such as `/api/sessions` or `/api/index.php/sessions`, it loads the homepage `/index.html`.

Comment: When you say does not work, what do you mean? Is nginx throwing 404s or another error or are you getting NotFoundHttpExceptions (from laravel)? or something else?

Comment: No, it loads the homepage `/index.html`. I'll update the question with more detail

Comment: Why would you change Laravels structure? i don't get that.

Answer (score 0):

My situation was a little bit different from yours, because I've done my best to keep the Angular and Laravel applications in separate directories, and in separate source control, but I was facing the exact same challenges as you, and my solution is below.

The key difference is the use of "alias" in the .php$ location. It tells nginx to use a different base path to start looking for files, which will help it correctly find the index.php. This is necessary because Angular and Laravel need to reference files from different base paths.

```
server {
    listen   80;

    root /path/to/application/app/public; # Path to Public
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name mysite.com;

    # AnuglarJS UI Front /index.html
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/
    }

    # Laravel Back-end /api/index.php
    location /api/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string; # Minor adjustment here - a simpler solution that achieves the same thing
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
    location ~ \.php$ {
        #---------------------------------------------------------------
        alias /path/to/application/app/public/api; # Path to directory containing index.php
        #---------------------------------------------------------------                try_files $uri / =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope each host should have a seperate nginx conf file. I am into the same case and trying to solve, once done will post a proper answer.